ASP.NET Core merge claims of two OAuth schemes
I have a cookie authentication scheme and 2 OAuth2 authentication schemes set up in my application. The way I'm using them is that to sign-in/sing-up the user uses OAuthScheme1 and then they can optionally link their second provider account using OAuthScheme2.
I successfully managed to set up the schemes but the issue I'm having is that OAuthScheme2's OnCreatingTicket callback overwrites OAuthScheme1's identity in the cookie and vice-versa. How can I merge the identities into one ClaimsPrincipal instead?
Here's what I tried:
options.Events.OnCreatingTicket = async =>
{
    context.RunClaimActions(JsonDocument.Parse(userData).RootElement);

    IEnumerable<Claim> mergedClaims = principal.Claims.Union(context.Principal.Claims);
    ClaimsIdentity mergedIdentity = new(mergedClaims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    ClaimsPrincipal mergedPrincipal = new(mergedIdentity);

    await context.HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, mergedPrincipal);
}


You can try to get the identity of the currently logged-in user in OAuthScheme2's OnCreatingTicket first. The Claims returned by OAuthScheme2 are then added to the current user's ClaimsPrincipal. After the Claims are merged, update the cookie to save the new ClaimsPrincipal.

I updated my question with what I tried to implement your solution but the second OAuth scheme is still overwriting the cookie even though the merged principal contains is correctly created with all the claims.
